# Is equicontinuity a necessary condition for the result of Arzela- Ascoli Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The result shows the existence of a uniformly convergent sub-sequence of the original sequence i.e. some kind of limiting behavior. So, can equi-continuity be relaxed to some kind of limiting ($\limsup) form of it ?

Thanks

Comment: If the whole family is not equicontinuous then you must only need to remove at most finitely many functions from the family to make it equicontinuous. Else it will not hold for the family of functions in question.

Have you read and understood the proof of the theorem?

Comment: @Pelto: Actually, I have read in a book that equi-continuity in the extended sense is enough (we don't even need each of the functions in the sequence be continuous)which is defined as  $\forall \epsilon >0$ there exist $\delta$ such that $\forall x,y $ with $|x-y| < \delta$

$$\limsup_{n} |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < \epsilon$$. Then the result says that there will be  a uniformly convergent sub-sequence for each bounded interval.

Comment: Suppose you have a family of functions $\{f_n\}$ with the property that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \sup |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$. Then clearly there is an infinite subfamily that is equicontinuous, which is exactly what I said.